# $ABCD$ is an iscribable quadrilateral. Prove $AB+CD=AD+BC$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am self-studying from Gerry Leversha's *Crossing the Bridge*, and I got stuck on this problem:

> $ABCD$ is an iscribable quadrilateral. Prove $AB+CD=AD+BC$.

I attempted a proof using trigonometry, but I suspect there is a more elementary way.

My attempt is as follows:
Let the centre be $O$ and join the vertices to $O$. Then define $\alpha:=\angle AOB,\beta:=\angle BOC,\gamma:=\angle COD,\delta:=\angle DOA$. Then $AB=2r\sin\alpha$ and similar results hold for the other sides. It suffices to prove $\sin\alpha+\sin\gamma=\sin\beta+\sin\delta$. I then tried to use the sum to product formulas and almost got there but not quite because $\cos\left(\frac{\alpha-\gamma}{2}\right)\neq\cos\left(\frac{\beta-\delta}{2}\right)$.

I also tried to use similar triangles, letting $E:=AC\cap BD$ and then it easily follows that $\triangle ABE\sim\triangle DCE$ and $\triangle BCE\sim\triangle ADE$, but then there are two different scale factors and the problem reduces to showing $AD/DC=(1+k)/(1+k')$, where $k,k'$ are the scale factors. I also could not show this.

Comment: What you say is true for a  circunscribable quadrilateral but it is false for  an iscribable one. (except mi deficient English induce me to the wrong). Anyway, if the quadrilateral is inside a circle, it is easy to build a counterexample. And the proof for a quadrilateral outside the circle is basically the equality of segments of tangency from each vertex.

Comment: In that case, the question is wrong. My understanding is that inscribable means "can be inscribed".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I suppose inscribable means a circle can be inscribed in. If you mean this by statement, then we may write:

$AF=AB_1$

$FB=BE$

$CG=CE$

$GD=DB_1$

suming up theses relations we get:

$AF+FB+CG+GD=BE+CE+DB_1+AB_1$

Or:

$AB+CD=AD+BC$

This is the only possibility, in fact the correct statement for this result is:

A circle can be inscribed in the quadrilateral ABCD. Prove $AB+CD=AD+BC$.

Comment: You have proved the result for circumscribed quadrilaterals. Inscribable means can be inscribed.

Comment: @a1402, the statement is not correct. I included a correct statement in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The result as stated is false: consider an inscribed rectangle with width $>$ length, then $AB+CD\neq AD+BC$. As per Piquito's comment, the question should say circumscribed quadrilateral.